# Is it possible to have multiple sales email templates for one site?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, email-templates

I am in the process of setting up a multi-site Magento installation

My sales team need to have a variety of 'standard' blocks of text to send to the customer, which aren't standard Order Confirmation etc.

For example:
- "Your order tracking reference is:...."
- "Our bank details for BACS transfer are..."
- "Your payment has been flagged as possible fraud..."
etc

I can set up a new Email Template, but how do I add a button / section for the sales team to send it?
And can someone supply a list of all the emails that Magento sends, and explain where you can change the template used for that email.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't think this is easily possible.**

What comes in my mind is to add all the information to the order and then make use of `{depends order.attribute}` to add all the blocks conditionally.

More details:
You can use the condition `{depends $var}` which is like an `if($var)` in a template. Magento processes it if it is `true`, the part between `{depends}` and `{/depends}` is included, if it is `false`, it is not.

This way you can add a block for account infos, for order tracking, etc.

The second problem you need to solve is to get the information somehow into the mail template. The only way I can imagine at the moment is the order. And this way is bad.

The other way I just got in my mind is to kill the original magento order mail and instead implement your own (which I find quite simple), this way you have full control over the mail and you can add `$_REQUEST` parameter or whatever you want to pass to `{depends}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... can you explain in more detail please?

Comment: added a few paragraphs